# Visit visa to the UK - processing time?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, visa-rejections

My husband applied to come to the UK for a party that is going to be held on the 10th of February. He booked part of the venue, paid a £500 deposit, booked a flight and reserved a hotel from February 8 to 14. We have applied on January 15, went to appointment on the 19th. We paid for a priority visa, hoping we would get a decision before his flight. However we've applied before and he got refused.

Would they refuse the visa if we didn't allow them enough time to process the application?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72483/discussion-on-question-by-lucia-visit-visa-to-the-uk-processing-time).

Answer (score 4):

Tickets are not necessary for an application and best practice is that they should not be purchased in advance of a visa decision. Priority service is generally reserved for those with a clean application history, and you mention an earlier refusal.

Applications with a prior refusal are considered complex and are directed into the 'red' queue, regardless of whether priority service was requested. When this happens, the applicant is not reimbursed for the difference in cost, and the advertised turn-around time is no longer in effect.

Whether the visa would be refused for an insufficient amount of time would depend on the application's premise and the extent to which the applicant's bona fides have been established. Fortunately, some posts will just reject the application rather than issue a refusal. Hopefully, that will be the case, so that there will not be a second refusal on his record.

You can use this [UK.gov tool](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) to obtain information on how to contact UK Visas and Immigration about the application.

Comment: Thank you giorgio I’ve spoken to them but didn’t get anywhere as they don’t know when they will make a decision. If they do make a decision by friday we are still on the safe side. Otherwise the whole application will be pointless

Comment: @Lucia Isn't Feb 8 still 6 working days away? Why is this friday the limit?

Comment: @HankyPanky because paid more to get the passport sent back to us as it’s a long journey to Dusseldorf from the area my husband lives in. It’s 6 hours going and 6 hours coming back on a fast train.